# Run a changing number of variables in python

Tags: python, variables, discord, discord.py

So, I'm making a discord bot, and for that I am using discord.py . I wanted to use the move_member function to move many people from one channel to another, but it only allows you to move one member at a time, so, with the help of some people, I made the following system to split the members into individual variables.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   server = message.server
   cnt = message.content
   canalote = server.get_channel(message.author.voice.voice_channel.id)
   print(str(canalote) + " this is the channel id")
   members = canalote.voice_members
   canal_def = client.get_channel("destination channel id")

   member_ids = []

   for member in members:
       member_ids.append(member.id)

   for idx, val in enumerate(member_ids, 1):
       globals()["id" + str(idx)] = val

   if message.author == client:
       return()

   elif "move" in cnt:
       for int in range(idx):
            await client.move_member(server.get_member(val), canal_def) 


   else:
       return("nothing for me to do")
```

My issue is, I don't really know how I could run the move_member command once per every user in a channel while also changing the ID of the user it is moving. The bot grabs all the user IDs in a channel and puts them in a list, then using dictionaries it separates them into variables called id1, id2, id3...

I tried using "random.choice", but I cannot do that if I don't know which variables exist, and which don't.

How should I go about doing this?

Any feedback would be appreciated, as I am fairly new to programming.

Comment: Hey, white space is important in Python. Which is global script and which is part of your `async def`?

Comment: Just edited it, my bad.

Comment: "then using dictionaries it separates them into variables called id1, id2, id3" - get out of that variable-oriented mindset. It will not serve you well. Lists and dictionaries are already the appropriate tools for holding a collection of things; you do not need to use individual, numbered variables.

Comment: The problems you are experiencing are directly caused by your attempt to use numbered variables.

Comment: I frankly have no idea of what else I could do to move many members at once. The move_member function requires you to use a discord.member object. And I cannot use the get_member function with several IDs at once. So I've gotten myself into this mess.

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of the `members` list, then iterate over that list, calling `move_member` on each of it's elements:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

   members = list(message.author.voice.voice_channel.voice_members) # create a copy of the list
   canal_def = client.get_channel("destination channel id")

   if message.author == client:
       return()
   elif "move" in message.content:
       for member in members:
            await client.move_member(member, canal_def)
```